# Transform $y=sin(x)$ with a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trigonometry, linear-transformations

I want to transform the graph $y=\sin{x}$ by the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}3 & 4 \\-2 & 8\end{bmatrix}$, which roughly judging would give a clockwise rotation and a stretch.

My solution is to first parametrize the graph to get $x=t$ and $y=\sin{t}$. Then, I computed 
$$\begin{bmatrix}3 & 4 \\-2 & 8\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} t \\ \sin{t} \end{bmatrix}$$
to get the transformed parametric equations of $3t+4\sin{t}=x$ and $-2t+8\sin{t}=y$. My logic was that, by parameterizing $y=\sin{x}$, I am basically representing each point in the original function as a vector, and then transforming each of these individual vectors. When graphed, it looks like this:

[image]

Which seems more or less in agreement with my prediction.

However, I'm also wondering if we can transform a general set of coordinates $(x,y)$ and plug the transformed version back into the original equation as such:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 4\\-2 & 8\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}3x+4y\\-2x+8y\end{bmatrix}$$

Hence, I got $-2x+8y=\sin{(3x+4y)}$. However, upon graphing this function, I got:
[image]

This seems completely incorrect, but I cannot figure out exactly what went wrong. What does this second method actually represent?

Comment: Nothing is wrong, you just can't do what you're doing. It's because $\sin$ is not linear.

Comment: Is it because you haven't taken the inverse transformation matrix? [The second method using matrix inverse](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Divide%5B%5C%2840%292x%2B3y%5C%2841%29%2C32%5D%3D+sin%5C%2840%29Divide%5B8x-4y%2C32%5D%5C%2841%29)

Comment: @peterwhy do you mind explaining why using the inverse would work? Please excuse me, as I am just learning this topic.

Answer (score 3):

Using $x'$ and $y'$ for the transformed points, from your method 1,

$$\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}3 & 4 \\-2 & 8\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} t \\ \sin{t} \end{bmatrix} &= \begin{bmatrix} x' \\ y' \end{bmatrix}\\
\begin{bmatrix} t \\ \sin{t} \end{bmatrix} &= \begin{bmatrix}3 & 4 \\-2 & 8\end{bmatrix}^{-1} \begin{bmatrix} x' \\ y' \end{bmatrix}\\
&= \frac1{32}\begin{bmatrix}8 & -4 \\2 & 3\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x' \\ y' \end{bmatrix}\\
&= \frac{1}{32} \begin{bmatrix} 8x'-4y' \\ 2x'+3y' \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}$$

Eliminate $t$ by substituting $t = \frac{8x'-4y'}{32}$ into $\sin t = \frac{2x'+3y'}{32}$, to obtain:

$$\frac{2x'+3y'}{32} = \sin \left(\frac{8x'-4y'}{32}\right)$$

Fundamentally, the equation $y=\sin x$ relates the points before transformation $(x,y)=(t, \sin t)$. Writing $y' \overset ?= \sin x'$ directly with the transformed points *doesn't* work.

---

As for the meaning of the second diagram, the curve $-2x+8y=\sin{(3x+4y)}$ relates coordinates using the new basis $\mathbf v_x = \begin{bmatrix}3 \\-2\end{bmatrix}$ and $\mathbf v_y = \begin{bmatrix}4 \\8\end{bmatrix}$. (Both vectors are columns of your transformation matrix)

For example, the red curve is near $x_{\text{new}}=4, y_{\text{new}}=0.976$ using the new basis. In terms of the standard basis $\mathbf e_x = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\0\end{bmatrix}$ and $\mathbf e_y = \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$, this same point would have the coordinates

$$\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}x_{\text{std}} \\y_{\text{std}}\end{bmatrix}
&= x_{\text{new}} \mathbf v_x + y_{\text{new}} \mathbf v_y\\
&= 4\begin{bmatrix}3 \\-2\end{bmatrix} + 0.976\begin{bmatrix}4 \\8\end{bmatrix}\\
&= \begin{bmatrix}15.904 \\ -0.192\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}$$

While the actual $y=\sin x$ is near $(15.904, \sin 15.904) \approx (15.904, -0.195)$.

---

More about [active and passive transformation on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_and_passive_transformation).